# How to connect to wifi on Lubuntu (Can connect to home wifi but can't connect to any other wifi)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I am a bit new here so apology if you don't understand my question (leave in the comment what additional details you may require)

I can connect to my home wifi but I **can not** connect to any other wifi. I have tested my phone hotspot, office wifi.

Some details of the network (I am not sure if they are relevant or not)

```
cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ayaz

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

```
lsb_release -a  

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thank you all for your contribution! :)

Comment: You've provided no release details; the Lubuntu manual can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.5/nm-tray.html   (you didn't mention release; so that's the *latest* stable release or 21.04)   I don't know why you provided what you did, some release details though are a starting point.

Comment: @guiverc, I have added the details of release. Feel free to let me know if you need additional details

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: Also note:  if you downloaded it recently (ie. May 2021) then also check it's a legitimate ISO (did you confirm the checksum from an official Ubuntu/Lubuntu site? and not where you downloaded it?), as links were removed April 30, 2021 from the Lubuntu web site (you can still find it on cdimage.ubuntu.com so from there will be legit).  If you used google to look for where to download Lubuntu, many sites are offered, but only 1 is legitimate (and it removed links at EOL on April 30).

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, i will definitely keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly some misunderstanding.
This is how my desktop looks.
After pressing Select Network, you should see a list, then choose and you may be prompted for a password that you must have.

[image: Select network]

Comment: Thanks @Pierre, I can connect to my home network, but I am not able to connect to other wifi! Well on lubuntu we don't have this menu but we can connect by clicking in the bottom right corner and selecting network.

Comment: Do you have any password prompt or error message?  There might be a log file somewhere, you should look for it.  Can you try different wifis?

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your contributions.

I have solved my problem by going to  Menu > Preference > **Network Connections** > Clicking **+** >  Selecting Network Type (Wifi) > Providing Connection name and SSID the same as network name > Type password in wifi-security tab (which is the password of the network) > click save

After waiting for few moments it connected to my wifi, and it was an amazing experience

I wasn't able to connect to wifi quite frequently by using the option in the bottom right corner.